# Cannot find the .iso file to create a live USB disk

Tags: usb-creator

Hi, it may be obvious once you have read this but I am new to using Ubuntu 13.04. I have got it up and running, and I've been online so far so good. I am now trying to create a bootable USB stick, it's a 4 Gb formatted fat32 disk.

I opened Startup Disk Creator, the USB stick shows in bottom portion of the make a start up disc window and this is where it falls apart for. I click on other to select the iso file but it does not show up under desktop or any of the other places in the left pane. Any and all help will be gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: The iso is wherever you put it when you downloaded it.  Look in your Downloads directory?

Comment: It has to be an Ubuntu image for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

When you open Startup Disk Creator, you see in the Make Startup Disk window the following text: *Source disk image (.iso) or CD*. In order to get the ISO file that you need, visit the [Download Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) webpage.

Because the Ubuntu ISO is a large file, it is better to copy its link location and then download it with wget, because wget can resume broken downloads. To download a file from source `http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&more-stuff...` and save it to your Desktop, open the terminal and run the following command (for Ubuntu 13.04. For later versions of Ubuntu follow the 4 steps below the command to replace the Ubuntu 13.04 download link with the current download link):

```
cd ~/Desktop && wget -c http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&more-stuff...
```

In Ubuntu 14.04 and later replace the link in the above command: `http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&more-stuff...` with the link that you get when you visit the [Download Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) webpage and then follow these steps to get the URL of your download link:

1. Choose your flavour from the dropdown menu.
2. Click the **Download** button.
3. Click the link at the bottom of the page that says: *Not now, take me to the download ›*
4. Right-click the link to the correct iso file to download where it says *download now* and from the context menu select *Copy Link Location*. The exact wording of the *Copy Link Location* menu entry may vary depending on what web browser you are using. The link location is the URL of your download link.

After you have downloaded the ISO file, the md5 checksum hash is used for file verification. The [Ubuntu Documentation UbuntuHashes wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) contains all of the md5 Hashes for the different versions of Ubuntu. Let's assume that you downloaded a file called FILE.iso to your Desktop, and you want to find its md5 checksum. To find the md5 checksum of a file called FILE.iso, open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Desktop
md5sum FILE.iso
```

When the ISO has been downloaded and its md5 checksum has been verified, it is ready to use in Startup Disk Creator.